# I Have 108 Variables Outside The Class, Do I need To Declare It All As Global?

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/config.php');
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/lib/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/messaging/email-template.php');  // This is where the templates stored

class Email {
    public function sendEmail ($send_to_email, $sent_to_name, $template_name) {
        // this variables stored in config.php
        global $mandrill_host;          
        global $mandrill_port;
        global $mandrill_username;
        global $mandrill_password;
        global $mandrill_from;
        global $mandrill_from_name;

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = $mandrill_host;
        $mail->Port = $mandrill_port;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = $mandrill_username;
        $mail->Password = $mandrill_password;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

        $mail->From = $mandrill_from;
        $mail->FromName = $mandrill_from_name;
        $mail->AddAddress($send_to_email, $sent_to_name);

        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        // I will have CASE here to select $subject, $body and $body_txt
        // from /assets/messaging/email-template.php
        // based on $template_name parameter

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = $body_txt;

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
           echo 'Message could not be sent.';
           echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           exit;
        }

    }
}
```

the problem is, I have 36 different email templates in `email-template.php` file. and each template has 3 different variables : `$subject_1, $body_1, $body_txt_1`

do I have to declare all of those variables as global? or there's another better way to use variables outside PHP class?

thank you and I really appreciate your answer

Comment: You can return them in an array or you can put them into a public property. (Also if I see `$body_txt_1` you probably want to look into using arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run away from **Global**, it's evil ! :) 
First thing, you can put all of your `global $mandrill_*;` in a properties file, and load/read them using [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-ini-file.php)
Also, i suggest to you to put all of your templates in different **xml/xsd** or **json** files and to create a **properties/ini** file where you will put their path...

Answer (score 2):

It's never a good idea to put your variables in global state. It can make testing and debugging a nightmare. I recommend you create a `Config()` class and put your variables there. This class can have a `getConfig($itemName)` method which will return the value of the variable you request.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) nice answer :) ... but i think that it's more raisonable to store anything related to configuration in config folder/file

Comment: @HalayemAnis Agreed. And that's how most frameworks and apps do it. But going from global variables to config file might be too much at one go. So it might be better if we do it in the class to start with.